# Why is xmm11 not preserved accross call in optimized code?

Tags: visual-c++, sse

I have a C++ program and DLL, both of which have been optimized with MSVC /O2 option, 64 bit.

The program calls a function in the DLL as follows (pseudocode):

```cpp
auto const scale = 255.0f;

auto result = Foobar(...,  scale, ...);
```

with

```cpp
auto Foobar(...,  float const scale, ...) {
   ... // use scale here

// A
   ptr->Dll::Function(...); // does not pass scale here
// B
   ...
}
```

Note: `ptr` is a pointer to a class that was imported with `__decspec(dllimport)`.

The value of `scale` is stored in register `xmm11`, and is correct before the call to the dll function (point A above) but is incorrect after the call (B).

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-software-conventions?view=msvc-160#register-usage `xmm11` should be non-volatile, however, it does not seem to be preserved.

Is this a compiler bug, or is something else going on?

This problem does not exhibit itself if `/Og-` is added, and seems to happen in msvc toolset versions for both 2017 and 2019.

Comment: I can't say much about MSVC, but I don't think you can rely on any variable being stored inside a specific register -- even if `Function` itself does preserve it. For example, the caller could decide to move variables around. But maybe post a self-contained [mre] of the behavior your observe ...

Comment: You're going to need to look at the asm for the caller, not the C++ source.  If `scale` isn't used in the rest of the function, it might just have decided to use XMM11 for something else, or to restore the caller's value at that point.  i.e. you might be single-stepping past an instruction that modifies XMM11, and blaming it on the function call.  Or maybe you're calling a function that's not ABI-compliant.

Comment: I did look at the asm, debugged it to the point of the call instruction watching the contents of xmm11 before and after that instruction. Creating a minimal reproducible example is difficult and time consuming, but I might go that route if required.